# OKHttp / retrofit: thread-safety / immutability of Call data

Tags: thread-safety, immutability, okhttp

Can I pass the `requestBody()` `headers()` or anything else I retrieve from a finished OkHttp `Call<>` around to other threads, or is it necessary to copy the relevant data first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `RequestBody` to another thread, but only one thread is allowed to read the body. If multiple threads attempt to read it, you’re going to have a bad time.

Request and response headers are immutable.

Comment: Thanks. Out of curiosity: Are you the Jesse Wilson that worked on GlazedLists?

Comment: Yup! That’s me.

Comment: Awesome. I really enjoy your work. GL comes in handy a lot, using it now on Android (along with okhttp ;) ).